# Refreshing Combobox and Datagrid after deleting or adding data

Tags: datagrid, combobox

I am on a roll today.

Basically, after adding data via ComboBox to SQL I would like the ComboBox to auto refresh to show the updated data. Likewise, after deleting data in a Datagrid, I need the datagrid to referesh and show updated data from SQL.

I have tried:

```
ComboBox1.Refresh()
```

and:

```
DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

and:

```
Form1.Refresh()
```

None of them work.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using `dataset`?

Comment: Yes. I am using Dataset

Comment: there for just fill your database again.

Comment: How to I refill it? As in, how would I code that and where?

Comment: Ok, I have tried this solution that I found in a google search but just throws an error about Overload -             mycommand.Dispose()
            SqlDataAdapter.Fill(Form1.RioDiaryDataSet5.MyDiary, "sp_FormData_All")

Comment: I have tried everything folks. Has anyone got a code sample I can use?